# How to push key value pair to post data array Sentinel Register

Tags: laravel-5, cartalyst-sentinel

I created new column to  my user table through database for uploading profile_pic image details 
but when i am trying to push upload image name to $request::all() its doesn't saves image name in database when
Sentinel::register() get called other columns get filled.

$request['profile_pic'] = $safeName;

this what the way i am using to push details in $request array

Comment: You have to add 'profile_pic' in your fillable array of EloquentModel